# Is it possible to pattern match on Iterable

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

It there an elegant way to pattern match on a scala `Iterable[A]` collection, to check if it's empty, if it contains exactly one element (and get it), if it contains exactly N elements (and get them), if it contains at least one or more elements (and get it or them), and so on.

With `List` it's trivial, but I'm not able to have the equivalent for `Iterable` working.

Comment: looks like you are always using the whole `Iterable` anyway. if `one element => get it`, if `iterable.size >=1 get it`, if `n elements => get it`, which means those conditions will always be true. Only thing you missed is 0 elem.

Comment: they are just examples of possible matches

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you want to do pattern matching in the following way?

```
val it: Iterable[Int] = ...
it match {
  case Iterable(1, a, b) => ...
  case Iterable(a, b) => ...
  case Iterable() =>
}
```

If yes, actually you can't do it because Iterable's companion object doesn't have `unapplySeq` method. So the easiest way to do so is explicitly converting `Iterable` to `Seq`:

```
val it: Iterable[Int] = ...
it.toSeq match {
  case Seq(1, a, b) => ...
  case Seq(a, b) => ...
  case Seq() =>
}
```

Or if you don't want to convert `Iterable` to `Seq` every time by hand, you can use something like this:

```
object iterable {
  def unapplySeq[A](it: Iterable[A]): Option[Seq[A]] = Some(it.toSeq)
}
val it: Iterable[Int] = ...
it match {
  case iterable(1, a, b) => ...
  case iterable(a, b) => ...
  case iterable() =>
}
```

But be aware that underlying collection may not be a `Seq`. This approach may lead to copying the whole `Iterable` into a new collection.

EDIT:

`Iterable` may be infinite. In this case `.toSeq` may crash your program.
So the safest way will be calling `.take(n)` before pattern matching

Comment: Very good hints, thanks. Please note toSeq doesn't terminate for infinite Iterable collections. We may first call take(n) and then toSeq or directly toList and use list pattern matching. I wanted to do it directly on Iterable without converting it, but it seems not possible. Anyway, please amend your answer, we'll keep it documented with the safest and best way we find.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
   object Example extends App {

     val myIterable: Iterable[Int] = List(1,2).toIterable

     myIterable match {
        case Nil =>
            println(s" list is empty")
        case a::Nil =>
            println(s" list contains 1 elements $a")
        case a::b::Nil =>
            println(s" list contains 2 elements $a and $b")
    }
  }
```

Comment: This works only because in your example the original object is a List. I think it doesn't work in the general case, try please with an Array to quickly check it.